# Getting Weird Output on Java (New to Code)

Tags: java, output

The input is April 3,2013 and the output should be 3-April-2013 however I keep getting the output of `3, 2013-Apri-20`

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class DateConversion {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner ( System.in );


    System.out.println("Enter the date: ");
    String temp = sc.nextLine();

    String day =temp.substring(6);
    String month = temp.substring(0, 4);
    String year = temp.substring(9, 12);

    System.out.println(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);

    sc.close();


     }
   }
```

Comment: Read [the](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't be closing `System.in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String class `substring` method  split the string from startposition to endposition-1 `substring(start, end-1)`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner ( System.in );


    System.out.println("Enter the date: ");
    String temp = sc.nextLine();

    String day =temp.substring(6,7);
    String month = temp.substring(0, 5);
    String year = temp.substring(8, 12);

    System.out.println(day + "-" + month + "-" + year); //3-April-2013

    sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `day` substring only includes one value (so it starts from the sixth character to the end of the input). I would use `String.split` to get the tokens instead. Like,

```
String temp = "April 3,2013";
String[] tokens = temp.split("[\\s,]");
System.out.printf("%s-%s-%s%n", tokens[1], tokens[0], tokens[2]);
```